# using AWSDynamoDBScanExpression to find all objects with the key inside a list

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-dynamodb, fetch, aws-sdk

I have a list of Keys [key1, key2, key3] (in my groups object as an NSArray) and I want to find all the values in my DynamoDB `Groups` table using Objective-C.

Should be a simple task, but I'm encountering an error and I'm a little confused on how I should forming my `filterExpression` for `AWSDynamoDBScanExpression` object:

```
AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *sc = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];

sc.limit = @10;
sc.filterExpression = @"GroupID IN :val";
sc.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":val":groups};

[[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[Group class] expression:sc] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
              if (task.error) {
                  NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
              }
              if (task.exception) {
                  NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
              }
              if (task.result) {
                  AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *output = task.result;
                  NSArray *items = output.items; 
             }
              return nil;
          }];
```

Error:

> The request failed. Error: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSDynamoDBErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException, message=Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: ":val", near: "IN :val"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If u want to find all values u should just do following

   ```
   [[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[Group class] [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new]] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
       //do stuff with (AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput obj).items -> should contain object of class Group
       return nil;
   }];
   ```
2. If u want to add some filter u can configure `AWSDynamoDBScanExpression` something like

   ```
   AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [[AWSDynamoDBScanExpression alloc] init];

   scanExpression.expressionAttributeNames = @{
                                               @"#P": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", <propertyNameToFileter>]
                                               };
   scanExpression.filterExpression = @"#P = :val";
   scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{
                                                @":val" : <filterCriteriaForProperty>
                                                };
   ```

and call same scan method.

In both cases u will receive object `AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput`

> Printing description of task->_result: 
>   AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput: 0x7ff8faf56cc0

[image]